# Java System.out.print(3/2) почему выводит целое число?

Tags: java, преобразование-типов, приведение

System.out.print(3/2) результат в консоли '1', почему выводит целое число? неявное приведение типов??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делите одно целое число на другое целое число, в результате получаете целое число. Если хотите получить вещественное число то напишите так

```
System.out.print(3.0/2)
```